# Flutter Switch Toggle not updating in PopUpMenuButton

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am using PopUpMenuButton for my Flutter app and this is my Full code,
Actually, My app is working the functionality of the App by clicking on the Switch Toggle, Just not Updating the Toggle State (which Means: I am not getting Switch toggle animation).

```
class NavvBarItem extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NavvBarItemState createState() => _NavvBarItemState();
}

class _NavvBarItemState extends State<NavvBarItem> {
  late SharedPreferences _prefs;
  bool notificationsEnabled = true; // Set your default value here

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadNotificationPrefs();
  }

  Future<void> _loadNotificationPrefs() async {
    _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      notificationsEnabled = _prefs.getBool('notificationsEnabled') ?? true;
    });
  }

  Future<void> _toggleNotifications(bool value) async {
    setState(() {
      notificationsEnabled = value;
    });
    await _prefs.setBool('notificationsEnabled', value);
    print('Notification state changed: $value');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Menu"),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 236, 26, 25),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context); // Pop the current page
          },
        ),
        actions: [
          PopupMenuButton(
            onSelected: (String value) {
              switch (value) {
                case 'Option 5':
                  setState(() {
                    notificationsEnabled = !notificationsEnabled;
                  });
                  _toggleNotifications(notificationsEnabled);
                  break;
              }
            },
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuEntry<String>>[
              PopupMenuItem(
                value: 'Option 5',
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Text('Notify'),
                    Spacer(),
                    CupertinoSwitch(
                      value: notificationsEnabled,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          notificationsEnabled = value;
                        });
                        _toggleNotifications(value);
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: [],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Please suggest me to add the Switch toggle correctly, and I can not change my Layout because some reason.